# Is 'though quiet' in "He is friendly, though quiet' an adjectival adjunct?

Tags: adjuncts

Since *though quiet* in

> He is friendly, though quiet.

is non-essential to the whole meaning, it can be described as an adjunct. But what type of adjunct? My guess is that it is an adjectival one, but I am not completely sure because of the role that *though* plays.

If we consider *though quiet* to be an adjectival adjunct, then the 'core' of this adjunct must be *quiet*. Thus *though* is optional in the sentence, but then it becomes meaningless if we remove it.

Is *though quiet* an adjectival adjunct? If so, what role does *though* play in it?

Comment: "Though" is a preposition with a verbless clause as complement; it's the equivalent of "though he is quiet". The PP functions as a concessive adjunct

Comment: I can't seem to find a dictionary that lists *though* as a preposition, only as an adverb or a conjunction. Why is it so?

Comment: Some dictionaries do give this use of "though" as a conjunction while other more modern ones give it as a prep, see here "[link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/though).

Comment: *Though* cannot be optional. If you remove it, the sentence becomes ungrammatical: *✘ He is friendly, quiet.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *He is friendly, though quiet*.

I take "though" to be a preposition with "quiet" as a verbless clause serving as complement of "though".

For those who take "though" as a conjunction it is a subordinating one and "though quiet" is a verbless clause.

In both analyses, "though quiet" is a concessive adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a complex sentence.

> **He is friendly, though(he is) quiet**.

**He is friendly is the main clause** and **though he is quiet** is the subordinate clause.*Though* is a subordinate conjunction